# Prove or disprove $ \ (A \times A) - (B \times B) = (A-B) \times (A-B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Question:

Let $ A,B$ be sets.

Prove or disprove: $ \ (A \times A) - (B \times B) = (A-B) \times (A-B)$

My attempt:

Let $ \ (x,y) \in (A \times A) - (B \times B) \implies (x,y) \in (A \times A)$ and $ \ (x,y) \notin (B \times B) \implies x \in A $ and $ \ x\notin B$ and $ \ y \in A$ and $ \ y \notin B \implies (x,y) \in (A-B) \times (A-B)$

Let $ \ (x,y) \in (A-B) \times (A-B) \implies x \in A$ and $ x \notin B$ and $ \ y \in A$ and $ \ y \notin B \implies (x,y) \in (A \times A)$ and $ \ (x,y) \notin (B \times B) \implies (x,y) \in (A \times A) - (B \times B)$.

Is this approach correct?

Comment: How do you get
$$(x,y)\in A\times A\ \text{and}\ (x,y)\not\in B\times B \implies x\in A\ \text{and}\ x\not\in B?$$
What if $A=\{1,2\}$, $B=\{2\}$, and $(x,y)=(2,1)$?

Comment: Can’t you do it with a picture? Draw the appropriate big square ($A\times A$) and the subrectangles.

Comment: Good job on your attempt!  While there are some flaws in your proof (as noted in the answers below), it's clear from your attempt that you've spent some time thinking about this problem before asking for help, and for that, you should be applauded. :)

Answer (score 4):

No, because the statement is false. Let $A$ be $\mathbb{R}$ and let $B = \{0\}$. Then, $(A \times A) - (B \times B)$ is just $\mathbb{R}^2$ minus the origin, while $(A - B) \times (A - B)$ is the plane minus both axes.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof that $(A-B)\times(A-B) \subseteq (A\times A)-(B\times B)$ is correct. However, the reverse inclusion fails. Consider $A:=\{1,2\}$ and $B:=\{2\}$. Then $$(A\times A)-(B\times B)=\{(1,1),(1,2),(2,1)\}$$ is not a subset of $$(A-B)\times(A-B)=\{(1,1)\}.$$

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect. For example, if $A = \{0,1\}$ and $B = \{1\}$, then $A \times A - B \times B = \{(0,1),(1,0),(0,0)\}$,while $(A - B) \times (A - B) = \{ (0,0)\}$.

The reason why your answer is incorrect, is because of the following logic : If $(x,y) \notin A \times B$, then it is *not true* that $x \in A ,y \in B$ must *both* be false, it is enough if *one of them* is false. In the example above, you can see this clearly.

Even more obviously : Suppose $A$ and $B$ are finite sets, and  $B \subset A$. Then, the cardinality  of $A \times A - B \times B$ is $|A|^2 - |B|^2$, while the cardinality of $(A-B) \times (A - B)$ is $(|A| - |B|)^2$. If the sets are equal, then their cardinalities are equal, but when do you think this happens? Certainly not all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A$ has $a$ elements, and $B$ is a $b$-element subset of $A.$ Then the left side of your set equation has $a^2-b^2$ elements, while the right side has $(a-b)^2$ elements. For the sets to be equal, you must have $a^2-b^2=(a-b)^2.$ Is that always true?

Answer (score 0):

No. An example is $A=[1,3]$ and $B=[2,4]$ so sketch it in he plane you find it!

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect.

The set $A \times A$, is the sets where both coordinates belong in $A$.

The set $B \times B$ is the set where both coordinates belong in $B$.

So, $A \times A-B \times B$ are the points where both coordinates belong in $A$ except the ones that both coordinates belong in $B$. In other words, the first coordinates or the second coordinates does not belong in $B$.

Without words,
$$ A \times A-B \times B= \left ((A-B)\times A \right ) \cup \left (A\times (A-B)  \right )$$

Answer (score 0):

> Let $ \ (x,y) \in (A \times A) - (B \times B) \implies (x,y) \in (A \times A)$ and $ \ (x,y) \notin (B \times B) \implies x \in A $ and $ \ x\notin B$ and $ \ y \in A$ and $ \ y \notin B $...

No.

Indeed $~(x,y)\in A{\times}A ~\iff ~\big((x\in A)~\wedge~ (y\in A)\big)$.

- Any $(x,y)$ will be in $A^2$ exactly when both $x$ *and* $y$ are in $A$.

However $(x,y)\notin B{\times} B ~\iff~ \big((x\notin B)~{\large\vee}~(y\notin B)\big)$.

- Any $(x,y)$ is not in $B^2$ exactly when *at least one* from $x$ *or* $y$ is not in $B$.

---

Which is to say: 
$$(A{\times}A)\setminus (B{\times}B) ~{=~ (A{\times}A)\cap (B{\times}B)^\complement \\=~(A{\times}A)\cap(B^\complement{\times} B\cup B^\complement{\times} B^\complement\cup B{\times}B^\complement) \\ = ((A{\times}A)\cap(B^\complement{\times} B))~\cup~((A{\times}A)\cap(B^\complement{\times} B^\complement))~\cup~((A{\times}A)\cap( B{\times}B^\complement))\\ =~ (A\setminus B){\times}(A\cap B)~\cup~(A\setminus B){\times}(A\setminus B)~\cup~(A\cap B){\times}(A\setminus B)}$$